# Buffer I/O error on dev sdc logical block 418914480, async page read

Tags: debian, boot, hard-disk, proxmox

i get the following error message when i try to boot linux (debian). My sata cable of the hard drive had loose contact and fell off yesterday while running… Any tips to get the system running again?

blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdc sector … flags 0xb0700 1 prio class 0

i cant interupt it stuck at boot...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the device `/dev/sdc` physically failed. Boot from rescue environment, check SMART, use `ddrescue` to save the surviving data or send in to the professional data rescue service.

Hardware dies, this is not "if" but "when", and you must come prepared, so plan ahead and take steps to prevent it failing you.

Learn how to use RAID, make regular automated backups and monitor the health of your hardware and your backups. Proxmox has built-in support for ZFS and BTRFS, both providing redundancy, also it is possible to install Debian on MD RAID (a.k.a. Linux Software RAID) + LVM and convert it into Proxmox installation; it works perfectly like this. Proxmox also provides excellent Backup Server, which integrates tightly with the Virtual Environment and it is very neat, easy to use and efficient.

Comment: okey, i only have a regular backup of my vm's. Then i try to setup proxmox again and restore the vm backups. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when running virtual machine on ZFS. The ZFS pool was ok, but e2fsck failed giving for example the error:

```
/dev/zvol/tank/my-disk: recovering journal
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Run journal anyway<y>? yes
e2fsck: Input/output error while recovering journal of 
/dev/zvol/tank/my-disk
e2fsck: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/zvol/tank/my-disk
/dev/zvol/tank/my-disk: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
```

dmesg said:

```
[11284814.033303] Buffer I/O error on dev zd192, logical block 0, lost async page write
[11284814.033554] Buffer I/O error on dev zd192, logical block 1, lost async page write
[11284814.033678] Buffer I/O error on dev zd192, logical block 2, lost async page write
[11284814.033713] Buffer I/O error on dev zd192, logical block 3, lost async page write
[11284814.033733] Buffer I/O error on dev zd192, logical block 9, lost async page write
[11284814.033741] Buffer I/O error on dev zd192, logical block 1057, lost async page write
[11284814.033788] Buffer I/O error on dev zd192, logical block 1058, lost async page write
[11284814.033837] Buffer I/O error on dev zd192, logical block 1083, lost async page write
[11284814.033904] Buffer I/O error on dev zd192, logical block 1098, lost async page write
[11284814.033931] Buffer I/O error on dev zd192, logical block 1398, lost async page write
```

After some investigation it turned out, that the devices were physically ok, the root cause of the problem was that the ZFS pool was full:

```
zpool list -v
```

Showed that "tank" was 96.5% full. I have scheduled snapshots, and I deleted the older ones (from year 2022) by this oneliner:

```
/sbin/zfs list -H -o name -t snapshot |grep tank |grep 2022 |xargs -n1 /sbin/zfs destroy
```

I suggest running the commands one by initially without the unix pipes to figure out the right commands.

After this e2fsck worked regularly.